Is a function well defined?
Fix the following Enumeration
$\{f_\eta\colon \eta<\mathfrak c\}$ of $\mathcal F$, where $\mathcal F$ is a family of functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R.$
$\{\langle n_\eta, f_\eta\rangle\, \colon \eta <\mathfrak c\}$  of $\omega \times \mathcal F.$
$D:=\{x_\eta\colon \eta<\mathfrak c\}\subset\mathbb R$  where the elements of $D\subset\mathbb R$ are all distincts and $D\neq\mathbb R$.
Fix a bijection  function $h \colon \omega \times\mathcal F \to\  D.$ Also,  define
$g \colon \mathbb R\to\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$, power of $\mathbb R$,  as follows
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
(n-f(x),\infty)  &  \quad   x=h(n,f),\\
\mathbb R   &  \quad  \text{otherwise}.  
\end{cases}
$$
I know I gave a lot of information but I have to do that to ask my question which is about the definition of $g$.

Is $g$ well- defined function?

To see this,
let $x_1=x_2$. If $x_1,x_2\in h(n,f)$. then $(n-f(x_1),\infty)=(n-f(x_2),\infty)$ since $f$ is a function. So, $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$
If $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb R\setminus  D$, then $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$
Did I miss something?

To see if $g$ is well defined you need to show that, for each $x$, the value of $g(x)$ is unique. In other words, if $x\in h(n_1,f_1)$ and $x\in h(n_2,f_2)$, then you must have $n_1-f_1(x)=n_2-f_2(x)$.

@JorgeI.GonzálezC. Thank you for comment. Notice that $h$ is a bijection function. So, how did you assume that   $h(n_1,f_1)=x$ and $h(n_2,f_2)=x$. This is only can be possible if $(n_1,f_1)=(n_2, f_2)$ and so $n_1-f_1=n_2-f_2$

"$x\in h(n,f)$" makes no sense. $h(n,f)$ is a real number, not a subset of $\Bbb R$.

@AnneBauval, Ok, fix it .  Dose it make sense?

You forgot to fix after "To see this". Anyway, the statement ($g$ is well-defined) is now obvious and needs no proof. (Yours was a bit weird.)

Yes, $g(x)=(G(x),\infty)$, where
$$G(x)=\begin{cases}p_1(h^{-1}(x))-p_2(h^{-1}(x))(x)&\text{if }x\in D\\
-\infty&\text{else,}\end{cases}$$
$p_1:\omega\times\mathcal F\to\omega$ and $p_2:\omega\times\mathcal F\to\mathcal F$ denoting the canonical projections.

Anne Bauval, what is $p_1$ and $p_2$
